# Recorded video from webcam stops 8 seconds before end

Tags: flash, h.264, video.js, wowza

On my website I can record video from webcam using a flash appliation that stream to Wowza (installing on my server) which save video files.
Then when I read the video in browser with videojs or jwplayer, the video stops 8 seconds before the end, I tried with different times. The video can be read entirely with vlc.

The bug appears if I use in the flash script used to display the webcam and start recording, the codec h264 before stream.

```
//webcam.fla
function initH264Recording(nsPublish:NetStream)
{
    h264Settings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();
    h264Settings.setProfileLevel(H264Profile.BASELINE, H264Level.LEVEL_3);
    nsPublish.videoStreamSettings = h264Settings;
}
```

If I don't use this, everything works fine. But I want to use it because I can earn around 50% on the file's weight therefore on bandwidth.

Do you know why 8 seconds before the end videos stop ? 
Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Could you share a video example ?

Comment: Truying ending the publishing and closing the Netstream for the remainder of the video to go through (ie: wrap things up).. Also consider doing a version of like how it's **[shown here](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?1078-WOWZA-not-working-like-FMS-2-0-using-AS3&s=eae3c569cfabd49653b50bad33fb5d9f&p=5101#post5101)**. Things like `nstream.publish(false);` and `nstream.close();` should help your situation.

Comment: @akmozo https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u6ncm6r2lkar4sm/AAAU5TLFR4w9I6QyN8GOu1cFa?dl=0, you gonna find 3 video files, each stop 8" before the end in the web player.

Comment: OK I looked at the videos (cheer up) and for me they stops about 4 or 3 seconds before end. After using `appendBytes` method it stop about 2 or 1 sec before end. An improvement. So better to use that technique. You should look at **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899170/netstream-appendbyte-issue-with-h264-flv-video-stops-about-two-second-before-th)** for hints on playback code. I will test it myself in a few minutess to confirm it works okay

Comment: @VC.One The default wowza code was : `nsPublish.publish("null");`. I add  `nstream.publish(null)` (false doesn't work because this function take a string not a boolean) I also add `nstream.close();`. No change.  Then from the 2nd link you gave I add the event on onProgress function and add `nsPublish.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.END_SEQUENCE);`when recording is closing but no change too. Actualy I already tried to read the video with a flash player and it's works, but I prefer to use a html5 player

Comment: I am  using desktop app. Whenever I start streaming, it stops after few minutes automatically and there is nothing in wowza logs. Don't know what could really be the problem . Help!